# Iteration- Javascript

Tags: javascript, iteration

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var namIn = window.prompt( "Enter Your FULL Name:" ); var namAr = namIn.split("");

var namArLen = namAr.length;
document.write(namAr + "<br /> Length: " + namArLen); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When using this code, how do I add and a small iteration that will display my name in reverse order? So if my name were Ashley Smith the output will be my last name backwards then first name backwards on new single line in H1 size.

Comment: Have you tried a for-loop?

Comment: What **have** you tried?  Please try something and ask us about specific issues you're having.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
document.write("<h1>");
for (var i=namArLen-1; i>=0; i--) {
    document.write(namAr[i]);
}
document.write("</h1>");
```

For simplicity, there's also the [`reverse` function on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
document.write("<h1>"+namAr.reverse().join("")+"</h1>");
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Now my only problem is that it comes out with commas in between each letters and Length: 15...how do I avoid that?

Comment: @user2171570 - If you use the first example, you won't see the commas.  If you want to use the second example, you should read the [documentation for Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).  You'll be better off if you learn how to read documentation to solve issues like this yourself.  Bergi has put in the time and effort to give you 90% of what you need.  In theory you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: @user2171570 - Also... The 15 appears because your code **EXPLICITLY AND PURPOSELY** prints the length of the array!  You should remove the code that prints the length of the array if you don't want the length of the array to be printed ;-)

Comment: Oops, I forgot the parameter to `join`. The default separator is the comma.